# Git hook: enable echoing commands

Tags: git, githooks

is there any way to enable echo in git hook

```
/var/git/repositories/project.git/hooks/post-update

#!/bin/bash
unset GIT_DIR;
echo '========post-update hook========='

cd /var/project;
git reset --hard;
git checkout testing;
git pull;
chmod -R 774 ./lib

update-apps
```

desired git push output on another mashine:

```
#git push
...
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 5.98 KiB, done.
Total 10 (delta 3), reused 8 (delta 1)
========post-update hook=========
cd /var/project
git reset --hard
git checkout testing
git pull
chmod -R 774 ./lib
update-apps
```

this is just an example, actual command chain can be more complicated

and fail somewhere

should I redirect stdout to stderr somehow?

**UPDATE**

currently I have normal `git push` output and then `========post-update hook=========`
... and nothing

Oh! git version is 1.5.6.5

Comment: But what was your actual output when you tried?

Comment: check that the hook is executable (chmod +x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All output on either stdout or stderr should be forwarded. It's expected to work for all of `pre-receive`, `update`, `post-receive` and `post-update` hooks. Echoing commands is enabled with `set -x` in bourne shell.

Answer (score 2):

From `githooks` manual:

> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to git
>   send-pack on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for the
>   user.

But there was a know issue in some earlier versions of Git and also earlier version of Smart HTTP, whereby the output was not send. Update your git version and try.