# Python: Printing to standard out when running from a Gitolite trigger(hook)

Tags: python, git, io, gitolite

So on my Gitolite server I have a python script set to run from the trigger GIT_POST. All I want it to do is print some information to the client.

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import fileinput

def main():

    print "Trying to read input"

    for line in sys.argv:
        print line

    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Script initalizing'
    main()
```

Simple, right? Well, when I commit and push to my server I get this:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 244 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git-user:website
   fe07881..cfc7979  master -> master
```

Which contains none of the text it's supposed to output. I know this script runs because if change `sys.ext(0)` to `sys.exit(1)`, git thinks that the push fails. Also, if I run code that fails, the client recieves the stacktrace and everything.

I am running gitolite3 v3.5.3.1-1-gf8776f5 on git 1.7.1, so what am I missing here?

Comment: You could try something like `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`.

Comment: @ArgiriKotsaris that doesn't work but if I set it to `sys.stdout = sys.__stderr__` it prints.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but git 1.7.1 is way too old (April 2010).

As mentioned in "[Git hook: enable echoing commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7266902/6309)":

> there was a know issue in some earlier versions of Git and also earlier version of Smart HTTP, whereby the output was not send. Update your git version and try.

Comment: Tried updating, didn't solve my problem. I'm talking about Gitolite's triggers though, not Git's hooks.

Comment: @ILikePizza555 gitolite triggers are called by git hooks though (the `update` one: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm). But actually, that update hook is a gitolite perl script which in turn call the declared VREFS, so I will check why stdout wouldn't be returned in that case.