# gitolite post-receive hook not triggering

Tags: hook, gitolite

In my `.gitolite.rc` file I have:

```
LOCAL_CODE => "$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/local"
```

..then in `ENABLE` section of the same file I have enabled
`repo-specific-hooks`:

```
ENABLE => [

# COMMANDS

# These are the commands enabled by default
    'help',
    'desc',
    'info',
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    'repo-specific-hooks'
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
    ]
```

, now, on my local machine inside `gitolite-admin` folder I have:

```
gitolite-admin
...
...

└──local/
    └── hooks/
        ├── common/
        └── repo-specific/
            └── message* <-- this one I want to call in a post-receive hook!
```

, and for some repo in my `gitolite-admin` conf file:

```
repo foo
RW+                       =   @all
option hook.post-receive  =   message <-- referencing script I want to call on post-receive
```

I did `commit` and `push`, from `gitolite-admin` and I can see that my `message` script got deployed where it should be on the server path ( that $ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/local ), with **executable permsission set**.

However, when I push to `repo foo` I don't get echoed message from my
`message` script, which simply is a bash script:

```
echo "hello from message"
exit 0
```

Why does that `post-receive` is not triggering?

Also if I understood well, there should be a symbolic link in that `foo repo`
called `post-receive` pointing to my `message` script, and there isn't one.

Comment: Is your script executable (755)? And just to be sure, can add a `set -x` in your script? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7266869/6309)

Comment: `gitolite@remotemachine:~$ ls -l .gitolite/local/hooks/repo-specific/message`
yields `-rwxr-x--- 1 gitolite gitolite 88 Jun 26 22:35 .gitolite/local/hooks/repo-specific/message`

Comment: added `set -x`, cannot see anything except standard message after `git push`

Comment: Did you forget the '`,`' after `'repo-specific-hooks'`? the '`,`' is needed.

Comment: No it's there. I checked.

Comment: What version of gitolite are you using? Basically, it all comes done to http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cust.html#rsh "create a directory called `hooks/repo-specific` in whatever location you decided to use for your non-core code (i.e., direct on the server, or within the gitolite-admin repo)"... not sure exactly *where* that `hooks/repo-specific` folder is supposed to be.

Comment: It's said that it can be anywhere,  as long as you point to that location with LOCAL_CODE variable, there is even an example like the one I used

Comment: version is 3.5-something

Comment: Ok. An old one from 2013. Could you try and upgrade to 3.6.1?

Comment: Can I update by pulling from remote instead of making new clone, and how should I save changes applied by some previous patch? Because now, when I go into src dir, where I previously cloned gitolite, I have status showing modified that file I patched while ago (because of some problems relating gitweb). Should I commit those changes, and then do `git fetch origin/master`, and then `git merge origin/master`?

Comment: ok.. you were right, this feature wasn't available until version 3.6+ :) thanks again.

Comment: You can stash, pull, stash pop, and re-run `gitolite install`. I have added an answer for the release of that feature.

Comment: Yes,  that was exactly how I did it,  yesterday,   as you didn't respond. I took the risk ;-)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't respond because it was 11PM and I was asleep ;)

Comment: I do that kind of gitolite upgrade all the time, pulling and then calling the install script: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/95a9ccfc8c1cf2848e9580b4704cd0cea07ab6cf/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh#L23-L28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by the OP, the per repo hook is only available from gitolite late 3.5 (Oct /2013), 3.6 (2014), not early 3.5.x (2013).

'`repo-specific-hooks`' was:

- introduced in [commit 62fb317](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/62fb31755abb7ad93e17a6fe8880b74eb17086fa)  (gitolite 3.5.3, Oct 2013)
- formerly tested in [commit c0e36b3](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/c0e36b3e7f11bb67397d10f771e8b13e63bb605d) (gitolite 3.6, May 2014)
- debugged in [commit b607f55](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/b607f55bb273f56a0d9148031ce67cd5a9280f37) (gitolite 3.6.1, June 23d 2014)

So the very latest version of gitolite is needed here.

Comment: Yes, I had 3.5 March.